# Ansible issues extracting a value from host vars

Tags: ansible

I am looking at extracting the value of Ansible host from `hostvars`, however I am not just getting the value.

the purpose is to select a random host from a group and use the name and IP to create a VM instance on proxmox as a sudo load balanced way of creating VMs.

Here is my playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  vars:
    - testvar: "{{ groups['proxmox_hypervisor'] | random }}"
    - anothertest: "hostvars.{{ testvar }}.ansible_host"
  tasks:
   - name: Print Host IP Address
     ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: "{{ anothertest }}"
```

I'm getting

```
TASK [Print Host IP Address] ******************************************
task path: /home/ansible/ceh-ansible/test.yml:8
ok: [localhost] => {
    "hostvars.b550.ansible_host": "192.168.5.178"
}
```

but I'm expecting

```
TASK [Print Host IP Address] *******************************************
task path: /home/ansible/ceh-ansible/test.yml:8
ok: [localhost] => {
    "192.168.5.178"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a misconception of YAML to start with:

```yaml
vars:
  - testvar: "{{ groups['proxmox_hypervisor'] | random }}"
  - anothertest: "hostvars.{{ testvar }}.ansible_host"
```

Is creating a list of dictionaries

```yaml
my_var:
  - testvar: b550
  - anothertest: hostvars.b550.ansible_host
```

This will force you to access elements in a complicated way:

- `my_var.0.testvar`
- `my_var.1.anothertest`

While, what you probably want in your variables is a dictionary:

```yaml
my_var:
  testvar: b550
  anothertest: hostvars.b550.ansible_host
```

Then, you are not templating your `anothertest` variable, so, it should rather be:

```yaml
testvar: "{{ groups['proxmox_hypervisor'] | random }}"
anothertest: "{{ hostvars[testvar].ansible_host }}"
```

---

All this said, there is a way easier manner to achieve this, use the randomness as your `hosts` parameter:

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ groups['proxmox_hypervisor'] | random }}"
  gather_facts: no  

  tasks:
   - name: Print host IP address
     ansible.builtin.debug:
       var: "{{ ansible_host }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look into the following example

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    b550:
      ansible_host: "192.168.5.178"

  tasks:

  - name: Debug var
    debug:
      var: b550.ansible_host

  - name: Debug msg
    debug:
      msg: "{{ b550.ansible_host }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Debug var] *****************
ok: [localhost] =>
  b550.ansible_host: 192.168.5.178

TASK [Debug msg] *****************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 192.168.5.178
```

**Further Documentation**

- [`debug` module - Parameters `var`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html#parameter-var)

  > *Mutually exclusive with the `msg` option. Be aware that this option already runs in Jinja2 context and has an implicit `{{ }}` wrapping, so you should not be using Jinja2 delimiters unless you are looking for double interpolation.*
- [`debug` module - Parameters `msg`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html#parameter-msg)